# Doubt about third declension

Tags: etymology

I was looking at the words in the phrase, “et verbum caro factum est”, and at *caro* in particular. I am casually interested in Latin (and languages generally) but I do not know it very well. So obviously, I look it up in the dictionary. The table of inflections show us quite a disturbing fact, that the oblique cases and the plurals seem to have some kind of *n* inserted between the stem and the case marker. Apparently, the same goes for another perfectly ordinary third-declension noun, *homo*. *tigris* may optionally have a *d* inserted which could be related somehow. But it looks as though this does not affect all third declension nouns.

Let’s take the genitive singular. The lemma is *caro*, so what would we expect? I would have said the genitive singular should be *caris*. But it’s not; the genitive is *carnis*. And it will not do to suppose that the epenthesis of *n* is to satisfy phonotactic constraints, since *caris* is a presumably attested and perfectly valid word (it may be a conjugation of the verb *caro*, or an inflection of the adjective, carus). So why is everybody so calm about this?

It should be noted also that the *n* does not seem to appear in the Proto-Indoeuropean reconstruction, **(s)ker‑* or any other cognates in other languages (including Welsh, *ysgar* meaning separate; Albanian, *harr* meaning cut; English, shear, sharp, secateurs, etc. etc.)

Why is there a phantom *n* turning up in only some forms of *caro*? Is this related to the same phenomenon in other words like *homo*, and maybe *tigris*? Is this same segment found in other Indo-European languages?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you chiefly asking why the -n- is found in *caro, carnis*, or why many such third declension nouns' stems have a letter not found in the nominative? They're very different questions.

Comment: I like the idea of writing a question in English (child/children, dwarf/dwarves, man/men, fish/fish...) but finding the variation in *Latin* noun declension 'disturbing'!

Comment: @dbmag9 all your examples of English words have perfectly unsurprising etymological explanations

Comment: @cmw I am asking the first question, why *caro* has a phantom *n*. But I am expecting that the answer is relevant to the fact some other 3rd declension nouns have some similar kind of funk going on.

Comment: The *n* is regular; what's irregular is the fact that it disappears from the nominative. In general, the stem and the expected endings can be used to form the oblique cases. The nominative, though, has to be learned, which is why 3rd-declension nouns are typically presented with both the nominative and genitive cases.

Comment: The 'n' even disappears in 'Plato' (from Ancient Greek: Πλάτων (Plátōn)) and 'leo' (from  Ancient Greek λέων (léōn))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In masculine and feminine nouns of the third declension, stem-final /n/ is more often than not omitted from the nominative singular form, which will instead end in -ō. In a number of nouns, the oblique stem also contains ō, as it ends in -ōn- (e.g. sermō, oblique stem sermōn-). In others, the oblique stem ends in -in- (e.g. orīgō, oblique stem orīgin-). Carō, carn- is the only one I can think of where the /n/ comes after a consonant in the oblique stem. I’d guess carn- probably originates from syncope of carin-.
The different vowel lengths and qualities in the oblique vs nominative stems are from ablaut (complicated by leveling/analogy), followed in Latin by reduction of word-internal short vowels.

This is indeed an unusual area of Latin morphology. The usual way of forming masculine/feminine nominative forms is by the addition of the suffix /s/. I don’t know how the alternative pattern of nominative -ō with oblique -ōn-/-in-/-n- originated.

[Wikipedia’s article on Proto-Indo-European declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals#Sample_declensions) indicates that the declension pattern with missing /n/ in the nominative singular existed already in PIE (see the “Amphikinetic n-stem” table).

PIE *(s)ker- is the reconstruction of the verbal root that the noun is built on. That verbal root was combined with a suffix to form the word carō/carn-.

Comment: Could it not be from the omitted nominative -n being due to loss of nasalisation?

Answer (score 12):

This goes back to Proto-Indo-European.

There's a category of nouns in PIE that have **-Cō* in the nominative singular and **-Cn-es* in the genitive singular. The nominative *probably* came from something like ***-Con-s*, with compensatory lengthening, but I'm not sure why the **s* is deleted.

The PIE form would then have been something like **kérH-ō* (< ***kérH-on-s*), **kṛH-n-és*. Different descendants levelled out this irregularity to different extents; in Latin, the stem was made consistent between the different forms (*carō, carnis*), but the missing *n* in the nominative singular was not restored. In Greek, on the other hand, an *n* present in the stem was generally put into the nominative as well: this is why Latin N-stem nouns tend to end in *-ō, -onis*, while their Greek equivalents end in -ω**ν**, -ωνος.

(This difference was noted even by the ancients, which is why the Latin form of Πλάτων is *Platō* instead of **Platōn*.)

Comment: A laryngeal seems to be needed at the end of the root to account for the a-vocalism: *krH-on-m > *karonem by Lindemann's Law, with -a- then generalized from the accusative, and syncope (thus de Vaan).

Comment: @TKR Good point. I'm writing the laryngeal as part of the suffix for now until I can check a good etymological dictionary, because Wiktionary says *_(s)ker_ has no laryngeal, but I want to check a better source on that.

Comment: Ah, yep, de Vaan puts the laryngeal in the root as you say. Will update.

Comment: Oh I've calmed down a bit now. You're saying it's inherited from PIE, which would make it the same thing as what Russian's got going on with имя and вымя and several other neuter nouns. When I looked up the Latin cognates for these, *nomen* and *uber*, lo and behold, they are third declension nouns. This has probably got something to do with it.

Comment: @Draconis I am out of my depth at this level of etymology, but this cite: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-968X.12058 seems to say that body parts may have taken an "n" suffix originally indicating a "singulative function."  If *kérH- was originally a verbal root meaning to cut (and an ancestor of English "shear"), perhaps *kérH-Vn started off life as implying a single" cut" of a body part.

Comment: Tends to end in -ō, -onis, not -ō, -ōnis?